# Telerik MVC grid data binding using Stored Procedure

Tags: ajax, data-binding, telerik, telerik-grid, telerik-mvc

Am using a telerik mvc grid to populate a data by passing the text that the user enters in a HTML textbox. Once the text is entered, I have a button which once we click, it should populate a telerik mvc grid with data (data should come by passing in the text into the stored procedure).

I have the stored proc, I have the controls in place and I want to use ajax binding to get the data from the controller using a view model. Am new to Razor, please help.

Comment: Are you using entity framework or casting the sproc results to objects? If you are then its just like anything else, call an Action on a controller that in turn calls your sproc and you shouldn't have any problems. Just look at their filter demo and their ajax demo. I'm assuming you're NOT talking about their KendoUI..

Comment: I got it thanks. I was not using Kendo...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this demo, I think it is really close to the case you explained.

http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/Grid/Filtering?theme=vista